# Is it possible to write directly to final file with distcp?

Tags: amazon-s3, distcp

I'm trying to upload file to s3a using `distcp`.

`distcp` writes to temporary file first and than renames it to proper filename.

But user does not allow for update/delete. So I have file with proper size, wrong name.

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1       3738 2021-05-24 12:04 s3a://testbucket/.distcp.tmp.attempt_1621587961870_0001_m_000000_0
```

on s3  and receive an error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: File copy failed: file:///testfile.json --> s3a://testbucket/testfile.json
```

Is it possible to omit renaming and write directly to final filename?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html

there is a parameter :

```
-direct
```

Write directly to destination paths Useful for avoiding potentially very expensive temporary file rename operations when the destination is an object store

example

```
hadoop distcp -direct hdfs://nn1:8020/datasets/set1 s3a://bucket/datasets/set1
```

Unfortunately my distcp version is too old and hasn't got this feature.